# Angular 6, catching ' error/not valid parameter ' in activated route

Tags: error-handling, routes, angular6, http-error

I am facing a problem with route parameter error catching. Here is the situation explained below.

The route params are as follows for displaying data in components of navbar:

```
http://localhost:4200/{ company_type }/{ company_name }/{ org-id }/{ component_name }
```

The website is opening even when I change the `company_name` to any string and `company_id` to `null || 14cd156`. I will get articles when I change company name in route. But, when I change `id` I get an error 
`core.js:1624 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","url" ...`
The API doesn't check for company name. It only checks the company id company coming from route params. What I want to do is: to navigate to `not-found` page in case the `company_name` and `company_id` are invalid. Let's say, 
`company_type = consulting` 
`company_name = ABC` 
`id = 1` 
`page=Article`

In page `Article` when I change `http://localhost:4200/consulting/ABC/5/articles` to `http://localhost:4200/consulting/3edsads/5/artciles` the website shows data of Articles page. But, the data is route parameter is wrong.

**articles.component.ts**

```
  getOrgArticles(page: number = 1) {
    let queryParams = this.getQueryParams(page);
    this.queryArticles =
        this.service.getOrgArticles(queryParams).
            subscribe((data: any) => {

                this.page = page;
                this.pageSize = queryParams['per-page'] || this.pageSize;

                this.articles = this.articles.concat(data['articles']);

                this.pageCount = data._meta.pageCount;

                this.isLastPage() ? this.hideNextButton() : this.showNextButton();
                this.totalCount = data._meta.totalCount;
            },
                error => {

                });
}
```

**service.ts**

```
getOrgArticles(queryParams) {
        const qpString = this.queryString(queryParams);
        return this.http.get(`${this.api}/articles?${qpString}`);
    }
```

I really wish to find some solution from you. Thank you

Comment: I can't understand what's your problem, can you explain more precisely please?

Comment: I tried my best to esplain the problem. Which part is most not understable for you, please let me know

Comment: which component is returning articles' data? if you are using some services you should assure that these services are using company name